# How to do add/merge/concat two or more multiindex pandas dataframe in python to get below output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first Multiindex DataFrame **df0**

```
Attributes  Adj Close        Close          High
Symbols     AARON  AART      AARON  AART    AARON  AART
Date                                                
2021-12-01  111.3  512.2     111.3  512.2   114.0 519.5
2021-12-02  116.6  512.5     116.6  512.5   116.8 519.9
2021-12-03  117.2  522.3     117.2  522.3   122.5 526.0
```

Next DataFrame **df1**

```
Attributes  Adj Close     Close        High
Symbols     FINP   FLEX   FINP  FLEX   FINP  FLEX
Date                                                
2021-12-01  204.4  18.0  204.4  18.0   213.6 18.0
2021-12-02  204.5  18.7  204.5  18.7   206.3 18.9
2021-12-03  200.8  19.5  200.8  19.5   205.8 19.6
```

Now I want to get final dataFrame **df** as

```
Attributes  Adj Close                  Close                      High
Symbols     AARON  AART  FINP   FLEX   AARON AART  FINP   FLEX    AARON  AART   FINP   FLEX
Date                                                
2021-12-01  111.3  512.2 204.4  18.0   111.3 512.2 204.4  18.0    114.0  519.5  213.6  18.0
2021-12-02  116.6  512.5 204.5  18.7   116.6 512.5 204.5  18.7    116.8  519.9  206.3  18.9
2021-12-03  117.2  522.3 200.8  19.5   117.2 522.3 200.8  19.5    122.5  526.0  205.8  19.6
```

`Which function/method should I use to get desired output`

> Note: Here added columns information for both dataFrames

**df0.columns**

```
MultiIndex([('Adj Close',      'AARON'),
            ('Adj Close',      'AART'),
            (    'Close',      'AARON'),
            (    'Close',      'AART'),
            (     'High',      'AARON'),
            (     'High',      'AART')],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])
```

**df1.columns**

```
MultiIndex([('Adj Close',      'AARON'),
            ('Adj Close',      'AART'),
            (    'Close',      'AARON'),
            (    'Close',      'AART'),
            (     'High',      'AARON'),
            (     'High',      'AART')],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])
```

Comment: produce dictionary to reproduce dataframe

Comment: add the code the print by this print(df.to_dict())

Comment: @gilf0yle I didn't get your point here except that I can produce dictionary from dataframe. Can you explain little bit more ?

Comment: i was asking you to send me share dictionary code to reproduce dataframe as its not getting properlly read by read_clipboard() to solve the issue. richard answer was crisp do that

Comment: Okey, But every data I have used here, is not original data. I typed here (mostly) to demonstrate my issue. Since actual data can not fit here and looks ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply `pd.concat` them, and use `groupby` with `level=0` (to group by the 0th (1st) level of the index) + `first`:

```
df = pd.concat([df0, df1]).groupby(level=0).first()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
           Adj Close                      Close                       High                    
               AARON   AART   FINP  FLEX  AARON   AART   FINP  FLEX  AARON   AART   FINP  FLEX
Symbols                                                                                       
2021-12-01     111.3  512.2  204.4  18.0  111.3  512.2  204.4  18.0  114.0  519.5  213.6  18.0
2021-12-02     116.6  512.5  204.5  18.7  116.6  512.5  204.5  18.7  116.8  519.9  206.3  18.9
2021-12-03     117.2  522.3  200.8  19.5  117.2  522.3  200.8  19.5  122.5  526.0  205.8  19.6
```

Comment: can you share dictionary code to reproduce dataframe as its not getting properlly read by read_clipboard()

Comment: @gilf0yle `df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Adj Close', 'FINP'), ('Adj Close', 'FLEX'), ('Close', 'FINP'), ('Close', 'FLEX'), ('High', 'FINP'), ('High', 'FLEX')]); df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Adj Close', 'AARON'), ('Adj Close', 'AART'), ('Close', 'AARON'), ('Close', 'AART'), ('High', 'AARON'), ('High', 'AART')])` - it's ugly, but runnable :)

Comment: Thanks @richardec. I am trying to download stocks data from internet, It is coming in this format if I request for multiple stocks as a time. I just wanted to make single dataframe to save it in excel so that I don't generate unnecessary request for data from websites for each strategy.  Thanks Again. :-)